# Creating a search bar in retool with SQL and JavaScript with separated words

Tags: javascript, sql, retool

I am trying to create a searchbar in retool with SQL and JavaScript. The problem I have is that it needs to search multiple words separately.

The code I have:

```
select * from prijslijst_nieuw where productnaam ilike {{'%' + textInput4.value + '%'}}
```

This works, but only on exact matches. For example: `Grenen B Ruw 70%Pefc 25x150x3900`

If I search 'Grenen B' it will show. But if I search for 'Grenen Ruw' it won't show.

Comment: ```SELECT * FROM `prijslijst_nieuw` WHERE `productnaam` LIKE {{'%' + textInput4.value + '%'}}```

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL query will give you your desired result.

```
SELECT * FROM `prijslijst_nieuw` WHERE `productnaam` LIKE {{'%' + textInput4.value + '%'}}
```